# How do I change color and font of my bootstrap nav tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'd like to change the color, font and size of the bootstrap nav tabs.

1) For the default tab state, I would like to have the text of the tab labels to be color of #575757, font size of 16 pixels and the Lato-Regular font face.

2) For the active tab, I'd like to have the text color change to #3c5a78 and the Lato-Bold font face.

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/huskydawgs/Y7qGo2Kz62

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="content-section-c">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2>Sample Search Results</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="tabbable">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">APPLE<br>
                TREES
                               </a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">ORANGE<br>TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">PEARS <br> TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">BANANAS<br>&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">GRAPE<br> TREES</a></li> 
                           </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
              <p>126 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
                                                  </div>
            <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
            <p>75 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/05_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/06_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/07_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/08_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
              <p>144 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/09_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/10_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/11_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/12_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
              <p>170 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="pane5" class="tab-pane">
              <p>256 Results Founds</p>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
        </div><!-- /.tabbable -->
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-section-c -->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
        padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3C5A78;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0 0 16px 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #e9a39c;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #d4d4d4 !important; 
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover{
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover{
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

.nav-tabs{
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block; /* needed to center the list items */
}

.tabbable{
     text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add this css in your file.

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  color: #3c5a78;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  color: #575757;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add the font-family to those?

Comment: @user3075987 please read my answer and make sure which answer helped you the most. thank u

Comment: @user3075987 if you do not include lato font family yet, then please include following link.
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
And use font-family:"lato"; and font-weight:"700" for this class: .nav-tabs > li.active > a
And use font-weight:"normal" for this class:.nav-tabs > li > a.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I can see that you have not created the `@font-face` for your Lato-Bold, Lato-Regular. So, If you ever wants to use some external `font-family` make sure that you have a defined `font-face` for it. [You can learn from here that how to make font family](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Secondly, I have wrote some CSS Property in this **URL DEMO:**
I hope you can easily understand it, http://www.bootply.com/GB3f0moehB

Following are the changes:

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #e9a39c;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #d4d4d4 !important;
 /* NEW ADDED PART (START) */
 color: #3c5a78 !important;
 font-family: YOUR-FONT FAMILY !important;
 /* NEW ADDED PART (END) */

}

 /* NEW ADDED PART (START) */
.nav-tabs>li>a {
 color: #575757 !important;
 font-family: YOUR-FONT FAMILY !important;
}
 /* NEW ADDED PART (END) */
```